# xeditable - remove the underline

Tags: css, x-editable

I have this html and I dont know how to remove the underline:

```
<span>
   <span editable-text="entry.startTime" data-e-style="width:45px; height:28px; padding:0;">{{entry.startTime}}</span> - 
   <span editable-text="entry.endTime" data-e-style="width:45px; height:28px; padding:0;">{{entry.endTime}}</span>
</span>
```

This is how it looks like and I wil remove the underline:

[image: Picture]

**[SOLVED]**
style="border: none;"  did it

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

You can assign one class to the span elements holding the date like this and in css you can mention like :span.no_underline{text-decoration:none}

```
<span>
   <span class="no_underline" editable-text="entry.startTime" data-e-style="width:45px; height:28px; padding:0;">{{entry.startTime}}</span> - 
   <span class="no_underline" editable-text="entry.endTime" data-e-style="width:45px; height:28px; padding:0;">{{entry.endTime}}</span>
```

or you can try this inline style also:

```
<span>
   <span class="no_underline" editable-text="entry.startTime" data-e-style="width:45px; height:28px; padding:0;text-decoration:none">{{entry.startTime}}</span> - 
   <span class="no_underline" editable-text="entry.endTime" data-e-style="width:45px; height:28px; padding:0;text-decoration:none">{{entry.endTime}}</span>
</span>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. sorrily this does not change anything.